# Change the order of locks at magento home page

Tags: magento, block, html

How can I change the order of the blocks in my home page magento? I installed the ultimo theme and desire change the position of the static block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML Layout update field on the homepage to rearrange the order. Your theme may also have options in its configuration.

To control the order of blocks in an XML layout update, include a “before” or “after” positioning property in the code.

To place a block—either before, or after a specific block—replace the hyphen with the block identifier

- before="-"    Places the block at the top of the sidebar, before
  other blocks.
- after="-"     Places the block at the bottom of the
  sidebar, after other blocks.

Examples:

```
 <block type="cms/block" before="-" name="left.permanent.callout">
 <block type="cms/block" before="some-other-block" name="left.permanent.callout">
 <block type="cms/block" after="-" name="left.permanent.callout">
 <block type="cms/block" after="some-other-block" name="left.permanent.callout">
```